# Styling a React Native picker to align with text input

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to align a picker where the user selects a phone country code with a text input where the user enters the phone number. I'm using the NativeBase component but I assume this is similar with the standard React Native component.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 0.2 }}>
    <Picker note selectedValue={this.state.phoneCountry}
      onValueChange={value => {this.setState({ phoneCountry = value })}}>
      <Picker.Item label="US +1" value="us" />
      // other items ....
    </Picker>
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 0.8 }}>
    <Input keyboardType='number-pad' onChangeText={text => {this.state.phone = text}} />
  </View>
</View>
```

This is what the output looks like (including the previous input field and labels for better view):
[image: screenshot]

The issue that I have is that in the picker, there is a padding that makes the text not align with the input that's side-by-side to it. It also seems that the text is centered in the picker. I tried changing the styles on both the picker in the items to change the `textAlign`, `padding` and `margin` but none of these seem to be the source of the issue since changing them doesn't move the text within the picker.

Comment: Can you please share screenshot how it looks like?

Comment: Done, added a screenshot for context

Answer (score 0):

To align Text in picker Item, you should use textAlign property of itemStyle like below:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 0.2 }}>
          <Picker
            itemStyle={{ color: 'red', textAlign: 'left' }}
            selectedValue={this.state.phoneCountry}
            onValueChange={value => { this.setState({ phoneCountry : value }) }}>
            <Picker.Item label="US +1" value="us" />
          </Picker> 
          </View>
      </View>
```

just to help you I tried this code and below is the output:

[image]